# Как решить ошибку not enough arguments for format string?

Tags: python, pymysql

Пытаюсь сделать insert данных в БД.

```
sql = "insert into items (`resource_id`,`item_link`,`item_title`,`item_datetime`,`item_text_content`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
         cursor.execute(sql, (str(resource_id), str(item_link), str(item_title), str(item_datetime), str(item_content)))
```

Выходит такая ошибка:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/parser_goose_and_boilerpipe.py", line 83, in <module>
    call_all_func(resources)
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/parser_goose_and_boilerpipe.py", line 79, in call_all_func
    cursor.execute(sql, (str(resource_id), (str(item_link), str(item_title), str(item_datetime), str(item_content))))
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 168, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 147, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Позже исправил код таким образом изменив `values`

```
sql = "insert into items (`resource_id`,`item_link`,`item_title`,`item_datetime`,`item_text_content`) values (%s,%s)"
                   cursor.execute(sql, (str(resource_id), str(item_link), str(item_title), str(item_datetime), str(item_content)))
```

Теперь ошибка такая:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:PycharmProjects/parser_russian_resource/parser_goose_and_boilerpipe.py", line 83, in <module>
    call_all_func(resources)
  File "C:PycharmProjects/parser_russian_resource/parser_goose_and_boilerpipe.py", line 79, in call_all_func
    cursor.execute(sql, (str(resource_id), (str(item_link), str(item_title), str(item_datetime), str(item_content))))
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")

Process finished with exit code 1
```

И уже эта ошибка говорит мне что количество столбцов не соответствует значению в строке.
Возможно ли эта ошибка из-за того что у меня в `values` только два `%s` `%s`  значения?
Передал в `values` больше 2х значений опять выходит та же ошибка `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Comment: во втором, думаю, да. А в первом разберитесь со скобками

Comment: @splash58,что не так с скобками ?

Comment: может и правильно, но у меня вызывает сомнение скобка перед вторым str - `(str(resource_id), (str(item_link),`

Comment: @splash58,Скобки исправил таким образом `cursor.execute(sql, (str(resource_id), str(item_link), str(item_title), str(item_datetime), str(item_content)))`.Но ошибка такая же `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO items (resource_id, item_link, item_title, item_datetime, item_text_content)
                   VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''', 
                   ( str(resource_id),
                     str(item_link),
                     str(item_title),
                     str(item_datetime),
                     str(item_text_content)
                   )
               )
```

Comment: Попробовал сделать так как вы написали.Но у меня выходит ошибка что `self.` не определенно

Comment: @Raharasomaha я убрал `self`, попробуйте еще раз.

Comment: Ваш код заработал ! Огромная благодарность вам ! Теперь можете пожалуйста объяснить ваш код ?

Comment: @Raharasomaha, а у вас указано в sql, что значений будет 2: `(%s,%s)`, а вы передаете 5 значений, вот и ошибка. Соответственно, решением будет указать 5 раз `%s`

Comment: @gil9red,благодарю